# Help with this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I´m trying to solve this differential equation. (2x-y+4)dy+(x-2y+5)dx=0

Here is my entire work until now.
[image]

Now that i Have substituted the variable t I don´t know how to procede. My book answer is

(x+y-1)^3=C(x-y+3)

Comment: WA's solution looks frightning. ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%282x-y%2B4%29dy%2B%28x-2y%2B5%29dx%3D0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x - 2y + 5){\text{dx}} + (2x - y + 4){\text{dy}} = 0$$

$$\begin{gathered}
  x - 2y + 5 = u - 2v \hfill \\
  2x - y + 4 = 2u - v \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

$$\begin{array}{l}
(x - 2y + 5){\rm{dx}} = u(1 - 2){\mathop{\rm du}\nolimits} \\
(2x - y + 4){\rm{dy}} = ut(2 - t)du + (2 - t){u^2}dt\\
(1 - {t^2}){\mathop{\rm du}\nolimits}  + (2 - t)u{\mathop{\rm dt}\nolimits}  = 0
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l}
\frac{{{\mathop{\rm du}\nolimits} }}{u} = \frac{1}{{{t^2} - 1}}dt - \frac{1}{{t + 1}}dt\\
\ln (u) = \frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{{1 - t}}{{t + 1}}) - \ln (t + 1) = \frac{1}{2}(ln(\frac{{1 - t}}{{t + 1}}) - \ln ({(t + 1)^2}))
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l}
\ln (u) = ln\sqrt {\frac{{1 - t}}{{{{(1 + t)}^3}}}} \\
u = \sqrt {\frac{{1 - t}}{{{{(1 + t)}^3}}}} \\
v = t u
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l}
t = \frac{v}{u} = \frac{{y - 2}}{{x + 1}}\\
1 - t = \frac{{x - y + 3}}{{x + 1}}\\
1 + t = \frac{{x + y - 1}}{{x + 1}}
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l}
{\left( {1 + t} \right)^3} = \frac{{{{\left( {x + y - 1} \right)}^3}}}{{{{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^2}\left( {x + 1} \right)}}\\
\frac{{1 - t}}{{{{\left( {1 + t} \right)}^3}}} = \frac{{x - y + 3}}{{x + 1}} \cdot \frac{{{{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^2}\left( {x + 1} \right)}}{{{{\left( {x + y - 1} \right)}^3}}} = \frac{{\left( {x - y + 3} \right){{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^2}}}{{{{\left( {x + y - 1} \right)}^3}}}
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l}
\sqrt {\frac{{1 - t}}{{{{(t + 1)}^3}}}}  = \frac{{\sqrt {x - y + 3} \left( {x + 1} \right)}}{{\sqrt {{{\left( {x + y - 1} \right)}^3}} }}\\
x + 1 = u = \sqrt {\frac{{1 - t}}{{{{(t + 1)}^3}}}}  = \frac{{\sqrt {x - y + 3} \left( {x + 1} \right)}}{{\sqrt {{{\left( {x + y - 1} \right)}^3}} }}
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l}
\frac{{\sqrt {x - y + 3} }}{{\sqrt {{{\left( {x + y - 1} \right)}^3}} }} = 1\\
\\
\sqrt {x - y + 3}  = \sqrt {{{\left( {x + y - 1} \right)}^3}} \\
\\
x - y + 3 = {\left( {x + y - 1} \right)^3}
\end{array}$$

Comment: And... what about the constant of integration?

Comment: @Did: Plug it in as a factor, LHS or RHS. Calculation took me
some time. I fit a constant after I had finished calculation.

Comment: The point is not that you explain to me where the constant of integration should appear (I can deduce that by myself), the point is that this (accepted) answer does not mention any constant of integration. By the way, what are the logical relations between each line of your post? These seem to be simply juxtaposed...

Comment: @Did: I'll do it a little later.

Comment: Thanks Frieder. Have you got the book or any site where I can see the solution step by step. It´s because we learn here in other way. In fact your answer is right, but I don´t understand how do you eliminate the natural log in both sides of the equation and how do you find the last line of this expression.

\begin{array}{l}
(x - 2y + 5){\rm{dx}} = u(1 - 2){\mathop{\rm du}\nolimits} \\
(2x - y + 4){\rm{dy}} = ut(2 - t)du + (2 - t){u^2}dt\\
(1 - {t^2}){\mathop{\rm du}\nolimits}  + (2 - t)u{\mathop{\rm dt}\nolimits}  = 0
\end{array}

Comment: @Did: Math is hard, so communicating mathematical reasoning in clear, intelligible language is too much to expect.  I for one prefer arbitrarily formatted gibberish because I feel I am in the presence of an artist.

Comment: @ViniciusL.Beserra What? But you *accepted* the whole shebang, no?

Comment: @RonGordon Indeed, keeping one's expectations about this world at a reasonable level is the road to happiness. Clear, accurate math proofs? No way! :-)

Comment: @Vinicius L. Beserra: Apply on both sides inverse function, named
exponential-function.
Add both LHSs and both RHSs, look at the very first equation.
Here I'm doing my substitution.